# What does () => {} mean?

Tags: c#

I was reading Pulling the switch [here](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/08/17/pulling-out-the-switch-its-time-for-a-whooping/) and came across this code.

Can somoone please explain what is `() => {}` and what should I read up to understand that line of code?

```
var moveMap = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
{
    {"Up", MoveUp},
    {"Down", MoveDown},
    {"Left", MoveLeft},
    {"Right", MoveRight},
    {"Combo", () => { MoveUp(); MoveUp(); MoveDown(); MoveDown(); }}
};

moveMap[move]();
```

Comment: This is a Lambda expression, have a look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

> All lambda expressions use the lambda operator `=>`, which is read as "goes to". The left side of the lambda operator specifies the input parameters (if any) and the right side holds the expression or statement block

Basically you are constructing a new, temporary function here that just calls a combination of two of the other functions.

As seen above, the `()` on the left side means that it has an empty parameter list (just like your other functions). The `{}` on the right means that it executes several statements inside a block, which makes it a "statement lambda" that is called for its side effects, in contrast to an "expression lambda", which computes a value.

Comment: If it's not anonymous, it's not a lambda. Just sayin'.

Comment: Edited - it doesn't actually call the other 4 functions, rather 2 of them twice each...

Comment: Thanks @David! Should have looked twice.

Comment: No worries. I didn't notice first time either.

Answer (score 4):

It's a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). MSDN refers to it as a "statement lambda":

> A statement lambda resembles an expression lambda except that the
>   statement(s) is enclosed in braces.

The dictionary contains a set of `Actions` (delegates). 4 are explicitly defined, and the 5th is an anonymous function which calls 2 of the others. The last line of code invokes an Action (it retrieves the delegate from the dictionary by key and invokes it).

Answer (score 4):

`() => {/*code*/}` is a *lambda expression*, a convenient way to create an anonymous delegate that takes zero parameters. Essentially it creates a callable piece of code that in your case moves up twice and then moves down twice.

You are not limited to lambdas without parameters - you can create ones with arguments:

```
Action<string> callable = (name) => {Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}!", s);};
callable("world");
callable("quick brown fox");
```

Answer (score 3):

`()` this is anonymous function  with No parameters

`=>` is lambda operator (pronounce as Goes to )

Dictionary has been initialized with KeyValuePair, Last option is an anonymous function which takes no parameter and invoke other functions